# db sqlite returns null and i dont know why flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite, null

my db func

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
        import 'package:recipe_proj/model/recipe_model.dart';
        import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
        
        class DatabaseHelper {
        
          static Future<void> createTables(Database database) async {
            await database.execute("""CREATE TABLE items(
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
                title TEXT,
                description TEXT,
                time TEXT,
                steps TEXT,
                image TEXT,
                createdAt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)""");
          }
        
        
        
          static Future<Database> db() async {
            return openDatabase(
              'recipe.db',
              version: 1,
              onCreate: (Database database, int version) async {
                await createTables(database);
              },
            );
          }
        
          static Future<int> createItem(Recipe recipe ) async{
            final db = await DatabaseHelper.db();
        
            final data = { 'title': recipe.title, 'description': recipe.description, 'time': recipe.time, 'steps' : recipe.steps.toString(), 'image' : recipe.image };
            final id = await db.insert('items', data,
                conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
            return id;
          }
        
        
         static Future<List<Recipe>> retrieveRecipe() async {
            final db = await DatabaseHelper.db();
            final List<Map<String, Object?>> queryResult = await db.query('items');
            return queryResult.map((e) => Recipe.fromMap(e)).toList();
          }
          
          
          static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getImageData() async {
            final db = await DatabaseHelper.db();
            return db.query('items', columns: ['image'], orderBy: 'id');
          }
        
        
          static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> searchItems(String keyWord) async {
            final db = await DatabaseHelper.db();
            return db.query('items', where: 'title LIKE ?', whereArgs: ['%$keyWord%']);
        
          }
        
        
          static Future<int> updateItem(
              int id, String title, String? description, String time) async {
            final db = await DatabaseHelper.db();
        
            final data = {
              'title': title,
              'description': description,
              'time' : time,
              'createdAt': DateTime.now().toString()
            };
        
            final result =
                await db.update('items', data, where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [id]);
            return result;
          }
        
        
        
          static Future<void> deleteItem(int id) async {
            final db = await DatabaseHelper.db();
            try {
              await db.delete("items", where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [id]);
            } catch (err) {
              debugPrint("Ошибка: $err");
            }
          }
        }
```

my grid view

```
        import 'dart:typed_data';
        
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        import 'package:recipe_proj/search_bar/search_bar.dart';
        import 'package:recipe_proj/model/recipe_model.dart';
        import 'package:recipe_proj/db/db_helper.dart';
        import 'package:recipe_proj/main.dart';
        import 'package:flutter_staggered_animations/flutter_staggered_animations.dart';
        
        import 'detail_screen.dart';
        
        class Grid extends StatefulWidget {
          const Grid({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
        
          @override
          GridState createState() => GridState();
        }
        
        class GridState extends State<Grid> {
          List<Recipe> myData = [];
        
          bool _isLoading = true;
          bool isPressed = false;
          Color color = const Color.fromRGBO(248, 249, 243, 1);
          final List<bool> pressed = List.generate(500,(index)=> false);
          late DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
          dynamic _refreshData() async {
            final data = await DatabaseHelper.retrieveRecipe();
            setState(() {
              myData = data;
              _isLoading = false;
            });
          }
        
          @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
            _refreshData();
          }
        
          /*final TextEditingController _titleController = TextEditingController();
          final TextEditingController _descriptionController = TextEditingController();
          final TextEditingController _timeController = TextEditingController();
          final List<TextEditingController> stepsController = [];*/
        
          /*
          final _portionController = TextEditingController();
          final List<String> _ingredients = [];
        
          final List<TextEditingController> _quaController = [];
        
          int portion = 0;
        
          final List<String> _quantity = [];*/
          late Uint8List imageFile;
        
        
          void deleteItem(int id) async {
            await DatabaseHelper.deleteItem(id);
            _refreshData();
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                content: Text('Рецепт удален успешно'), backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent));
          }
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                return Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white54,
              body: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: _isLoading
                    ? const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      )
                    : myData.isEmpty
                        ? Padding(
                            padding: MediaQuery.of(context).padding * 5,
                            child: const Center(
                                child: Text("У вас нет записанных рецептов",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 16.0,
                                        color: aDarkGreen,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700))),
                          )
                        : Padding(
                            padding: MediaQuery.of(context).padding * 1.1,
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                const Text("Рецепты",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20.0,
                                        color: aDarkGreen,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 14,
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          isPressed = false;
                                        });
                                      },
                                      child: Container(
                                        height: 30,
                                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                            color: isPressed
                                                ? Colors.white
                                                : aDarkGreen),
                                        child: Center(
                                            child: Text(
                                              "Рецепты",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: isPressed
                                                      ? aDarkGreen
                                                      : color),
                                            )),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(
                                      width: 5.0,
                                    ),
                                    TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          isPressed = true;
                                        });
                                      },
                                      child: Container(
                                        height: 30,
                                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                            color: isPressed
                                                ? aDarkGreen
                                                : color),
                                        child: Center(
                                            child: Text(
                                              "Коллекции",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: isPressed
                                                      ? color
                                                      : aDarkGreen),
                                            )),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                                SizedBox(
                                 width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                                  height: 36,
                                  child: GestureDetector(
                                    child: TextFormField(
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      readOnly: true,
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                                              suffix: const Icon(Icons.sort, color: Colors.black26,),
                                              prefix: const Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.black26,),
                                              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                              focusedBorder:OutlineInputBorder(
                                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black12, width: 2.0),
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                              filled: true,
                                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                                      color: Colors.black12
                                                  ),
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                                              ),
                                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                                      color: Colors.black12
                                                  ),
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                                              ),
        
                                              hintText:'Поиск рецептов',
                                              hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black26, )
                                          ),
        
                                        onTap: () {
                                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => const MySearchBar()));
                                    }),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                FutureBuilder(
                                  future: DatabaseHelper.retrieveRecipe(),
                                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                      return GridView.builder(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                        physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                                        shrinkWrap: true,
                                        itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
                                        itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                                            AnimationConfiguration.staggeredGrid(
                                              position: index,
                                              columnCount: 2,
                                              duration: const Duration(
                                                  milliseconds: 1000),
                                              child: ScaleAnimation(
                                                child: Padding(
                                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                                                  child: Dismissible(
                                                    key: UniqueKey(),
                                                    direction: DismissDirection
                                                        .endToStart,
                                                    background: Container(
                                                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                                      child: const Padding(
                                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                            right: 20.0),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                    onDismissed: (direction) {
                                                      setState(() {
                                                        deleteItem(snapshot.data![index].id);
                                                      });
                                                    },
                                                    child: Stack(
                                                      fit: StackFit.expand,
                                                      children: [
                                                        Positioned(
                                                          left: 0,
                                                          right: 0,
                                                          child: GestureDetector(
                                                            onTap: () {
                                                              Navigator.push(
                                                                  context,
                                                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                                                    builder: (
                                                                        context) =>
                                                                        RecipeDetail(
                                                                          recipe: snapshot.data![index],),
                                                                  ));
                                                            },
                                                            child: ClipRRect(
                                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius
                                                                  .circular(30),
                                                              child: SizedBox(
                                                                  height: 200,
                                                                  width: 200,
                                                                  child: snapshot.data![index]
                                                                      .image == null ?
                                                                  Image.asset(
                                                                    "assets/images/Dish.jpg",
                                                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                                  )
                                                                      : Image.memory(
                                                                    snapshot.data![index].image
                                                                        .toString() as Uint8List,
                                                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                                  )
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        Align(
                                                            alignment: const Alignment(
                                                                -1, 0.93),
                                                            child: Text(
                                                              snapshot.data![index].title,
                                                              softWrap: true,
                                                              maxLines: 2,
                                                              style: const TextStyle(
                                                                color: Colors.black45,
                                                                fontFamily: 'Cera Pro',
                                                                fontSize: 14,
                                                              ),)
                                                        ),
                                                        Positioned(
                                                          top: 170,
                                                          left: 10,
                                                          child: Row(
                                                            children: [
                                                              Text(snapshot.data![index].time
                                                                  .toString(),
                                                                style: const TextStyle(
                                                                    color: Colors
                                                                        .deepOrangeAccent),),
                                                              const SizedBox(
                                                                width: 2.0,
                                                              ),
                                                              const Text('min',
                                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                                      color: Colors
                                                                          .deepOrangeAccent)),
                                                            ],
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        Align(
                                                          alignment: const Alignment(
                                                              1.2, 1.13),
                                                          child: Container(
                                                            height: 46,
                                                            width: 46,
                                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius
                                                                    .circular(30)
                                                            ),
                                                            child: IconButton(
                                                              onPressed: () {
                                                                setState(() {
                                                                  for (int i = 0; i <
                                                                      pressed
                                                                          .length; i++) {
                                                                    if (i == index) {
                                                                      pressed[i] =
                                                                      !pressed[i];
                                                                    }
                                                                  }
                                                                });
                                                              },
                                                              icon: pressed[index]
                                                                  ? const Icon(
                                                                Icons.favorite,
                                                                color: Colors
                                                                    .deepOrangeAccent,
                                                                size: 22,)
                                                                  : const Icon(
                                                                Icons.favorite_outline,
                                                                color: Colors
                                                                    .deepOrangeAccent,
                                                                size: 22,),
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                        gridDelegate:
                                        const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                            crossAxisCount: 2,
                                            mainAxisExtent: 256,
                                            crossAxisSpacing: 1)
                                        ,
                                      );
                                    } else{
                                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                                    }
                                  }
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
              ),
            );
          }
        
        }
```

my model

```dart
        import 'dart:typed_data';
        
        
        class Recipe {
         late final int id;
         final String? description;
         final String title;
         final List<String> ingredients;
         final Uint8List? image;
         final int portion;
         final int? time;
         final List<String> quantity;
         final List<String> steps;
        
        
         Recipe(
             {required this.id, required this.title, this.description, required this.portion, required this.steps, required this.quantity, required this.ingredients, this.image,  required this.time});
        
         Recipe.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> res)
         : id = res['id'],
         title = res['title'],
         description = res ['description'],
         ingredients = res ['ingredients'],
         portion = res ['portion'],
         image = res ['image'],
         time = res ['time'],
         quantity = res ['quantity'],
         steps = res ['steps'];
        
         Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
          return {
             'id' : id,
           'title': title,
           'description': description,
           'ingredients': ingredients.join(', '),
           'time': time,
          "image": image,
           "portion": portion,
           'quantity': quantity,
           'steps': steps,
          };
         }
        
        
        }
```

I get null when trying get the data that saved in sqlite database Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List' Please someone help me. Look my code please i need it very much.
I want also pass my model specific items to new screen, so in grid view screen i add gestor detector to pass their own screen for every specific item

Comment: Try adding try catches for db functions such as add, get, update etc. Maybe you are missing unhandled exceptions while adding to getting data.